# What is a robust way to detect the name of the private LAN NIC if there are multiple NICs on Centos?

Tags: centos, network-adapter, private-network

I am using the following to detect the private LAN NIC.

```
export PRIVATE_LAN=`ip a|grep "inet 192"|tr -s ' '|cut -d' ' -f8`
```

Is that robust for long-term? It does depend on the formatting from the ip command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you define "private" as "having an IP address in the 192.168.x.x range" (*not* 192.x.x.x!), you can use:

```
ip -json addr show to 192.168.0.0/16 | jq -r ".[].ifname"
```

(There might be more than one such interface. There might be zero such interfaces.)

If you don't have `jq` installed:

```
ip -brief addr show to 192.168.0.0/16 | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: I had to change it to this (no brief or jq):        ip addr show to 192.168.0.0/16 |head -1|cut -d ':' -f2|tr -d ' '

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a better method:

```
    grep DEVICE `grep -l "IPADDR=192" /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*`|cut -d'=' -f2
```

or without backticks:

```
    grep -l "IPADDR=192" /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*|xargs grep DEVICE|cut -d'=' -f2
```